# Android Decryption WRONG_FINAL_BLOCK_LENGTH (File Encrypted with Python)

Tags: android, python, encryption

I am trying to get File Decryption working in Android. The file i have has been encrypted from python using Crypto.Cipher AES: full code:

```
import os, binascii, struct
from Crypto.Cipher import AES

def encrypt_file():
    chunksize=64*1024
    iv = "96889af65c391c69"
    k1 = "cb3a44cf3cb120cc7b8b3ab777f2d912"
    file = "tick.png"
    out_filename = "entick.png"
    dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)+"\\"
    print(iv)
    encryptor = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
    in_filename = dir+file
    filesize = os.path.getsize(in_filename)
    with open(in_filename, 'rb') as infile:
        with open(out_filename, 'wb') as outfile:
            outfile.write(struct.pack('<Q', filesize))
            outfile.write(iv)
            while True:
                chunk = infile.read(chunksize)
                if len(chunk) == 0:
                    break
                elif len(chunk) % 16 != 0:
                    chunk += ' ' * (16 - len(chunk) % 16)
                outfile.write(encryptor.encrypt(chunk))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    encrypt_file()
```

Android Decryption function (main):

```
private static File main(String fname, File enfile, String IV, String key) {
    try {
        byte[] bkey = key.getBytes("UTF-8");
        byte[] bIV = IV.getBytes("UTF-8");
        Log.d("ByteLen","bkey:"+Integer.toString(bkey.length));
        Log.d("ByteLen","bIV:"+ Integer.toString(bIV.length));
        File aesFile;
        aesFile = enfile;
        Log.d("AESFILELENGTH", "aes length: " + aesFile.length());
        File aesFileBis = new File(String.valueOf(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toPath()), "tick.png"); //to be replaced with fname

        FileInputStream fis;
        FileOutputStream fos;
        CipherInputStream cis;

        SecretKeySpec secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(bkey, "AES");
        Cipher decrypt = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        IvParameterSpec ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(bIV);

        decrypt.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey, ivSpec);

        fis = new FileInputStream(aesFile);

        cis = new CipherInputStream(fis, decrypt);

        fos = new FileOutputStream(aesFileBis);
        try {

            byte[] mByte = new byte[8];
            int i = cis.read(mByte);
            Log.i("MBYTE", "mbyte i: " + i);
            while (i != -1) {
                fos.write(mByte, 0, i);
                i = cis.read(mByte);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        fos.flush();
        fos.close();
        cis.close();
        fis.close();
        return aesFileBis;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

The Crypto.Cipher module inserts the IV into the file as bytes 8-24 so i created this method to extract them:

```
private String IV(File enfile) throws UnsupportedEncodingException, FileNotFoundException {
    int size = 24;
    byte bytes[] = new byte[size];
    byte tmpBuff[] = new byte[size];
    if(enfile.canRead()){
        //run decryption code

        FileInputStream fis= new FileInputStream(enfile);
        try {

            int read = fis.read(bytes, 0, size);
            if (read < size) {
                int remain = size - read;
                while (remain > 0) {
                    read = fis.read(tmpBuff, 0, remain);
                    System.arraycopy(tmpBuff, 0, bytes, size - remain, read);
                    remain -= read;
                }
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    String IV = new String(bytes, "US-ASCII");
    IV = IV.substring(8,24);
    return IV;
}
```

From the Decrypt function i have checked and verified the key is 32 bytes long and the iv is 16 bytes long and both are the correct IV and Key. I know I am switching from a byte array to string and back again but that's just for testing.

I have looked at a few posts regarding this issue and so far have only found posts relating to the key being the wrong byte size or for decrpyting Strings and not files and therefor switching base64 encoding doesn't seem to apply. I think the issue is to do with the way Crypto.Cipher is padding the files as the first 8 byes look like junk (SO and NULL bytes) then there are 16 bytes of IV.

Comment: You did not apply the [padding](https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/cipher/classic.html#cbc-mode) in Python. this is first to see.

Comment: Thanks for your Comment. Im not too good with crypto stuff so i thought i was using a standard AES file creation method. the comment about padding help me see including the IV and the struct.pack() line was giving me the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the comment i added the Padding module from crypto: https://github.com/dlitz/pycrypto/blob/master/lib/Crypto/Util/Padding.py

im my python code i added:

```
from Crypto.Util.py3compat import * #solves bchr error
```

i also copied the pad() function from the Padding.py to the end of my code.

in the file writing function:

```
with open(in_filename, 'rb') as infile:
    with open(out_filename, 'wb') as outfile:
        outfile.write(iv) ##IV becomes the first 16 bytes, not using struct.pack() anymore
        while True:
            chunk = infile.read(chunksize)
            if len(chunk) == 0:
                break
            elif len(chunk) % 16 != 0:
                chunk += ' ' * (16 - len(chunk) % 16)
            outfile.write(encryptor.encrypt(pad(chunk, 16))) ##added padding here
```

Finally in the Java code i removed the IV finder function and updated the main function:

```
private static File main(String fname, File enfile, String key) {
    try {
        FileInputStream fis;
        File aesFile;
        aesFile = enfile;
        byte[] bkey = key.getBytes("UTF-8");
        fis = new FileInputStream(aesFile);
        byte[] IV = new byte[16];
        for(Integer i =0; i < 16; i++){
            IV[i] = (byte) fis.read();
        }
        Log.e("IV:",""+new String(IV, "US-ASCII"));
        Log.d("ByteLen","bkey:"+Integer.toString(bkey.length));
        Log.d("ByteLen","bIV:"+ Integer.toString(IV.length));
        aesFile = enfile;
        Log.d("AESFILELENGTH", "aes length: " + aesFile.length());
        File aesFileBis = new File(String.valueOf(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toPath()), "file.png"); //to be replaced with fname
        FileOutputStream fos;
        CipherInputStream cis;
        SecretKeySpec secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(bkey, "AES");
        Cipher decrypt = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        IvParameterSpec ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(IV);
        decrypt.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey, ivSpec);
        cis = new CipherInputStream(fis, decrypt);
        fos = new FileOutputStream(aesFileBis);
        try {
            byte[] mByte = new byte[8];
            int i = cis.read(mByte);
            Log.i("MBYTE", "mbyte i: " + i);
            while (i != -1) {
                fos.write(mByte, 0, i);
                i = cis.read(mByte);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace();}
        fos.flush();
        fos.close();
        cis.close();
        fis.close();
        return aesFileBis;
    }catch(Exception e) {e.printStackTrace(); }
    return null;
}
```

The new parts of the code take the first 16 bytes from the FileInputStream and puts them into a byte array to be used as the IV, the rest are then decrypted using CBC/PKCS5Padding.

Hope this answer can be useful for anyone else.

Comment: Nice. You solved your issue. The general problems I have seen in SO: 1) Encryption modes are incompatible, 2) key sizes are incompatible 3) KDF are not compatible, 4) IV forget 4) output encoding and decoding problems, 5) padding are forgotten, 6) paddings are not compatible,...